# play through an array of audio files onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html, audio

I have an array of audio files that I want to play through whenever I click a button. If I click said button, it will play the next audio file in the array. Also, if audio is currently playing when the user clicks again, the current track is reset and the next song plays.

Trying to figure out why I can't cycle through the array I currently have.

```
 var song1 = $("#sound-1");
 var song2 = $("#sound-2");
 var song3 = $("#sound-3");
 var song4 = $("#sound-4");
 var song5 = $("#sound-5");
 var song6 = $("#sound-6");
 var song7 = $("#sound-7");
 var song8 = $("#sound-8");

 var audioArray = [ song1, song2, song3, song4, song5, song6, song7, song8 ];


$(".click").click(function(){
   var i=0;
      if (i< audioArray.length){
         audioArray[i].trigger('play');
         i++;
      } else if ( i>audioArray.length){
         i = 0;
         audioArray[i].trigger('play');
      };
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated answer:**

Since you are using the native HTML5 interface, there is a `pause` event that can be triggered as well. Unfortunately, there is no `stop` event that would reset the time, however we can set it to `0` manually using the `currentTime` property.

```
var i=0;
var lastPlayedFile = null;
$(".click").click(function(){
  if(lastPlayedFile !== null) {
    lastPlayedFile[0].currentTime = 0; // [0] because we need a native DOM element, not a jQuery-wrapped one
    lastPlayedFile.trigger('pause');
  }
  if (i< audioArray.length){
     lastPlayedFile = audioArray[i];
     audioArray[i].trigger('play');
     i++;
  } else if (i>=audioArray.length){ // there was a missing '=' in this condition to work properly
     i = 0;
     lastPlayedFile = audioArray[0];
     audioArray[i].trigger('play');
  };
});
```

- [Here is a fiddle I created.](https://jsfiddle.net/L9Lob1zw/) I've tested it in Chrome and it works flawlessly.
- I suggest [looking at the audio tag reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp) to see what more you can achieve by manipulating the native DOM audio element.

---

Original answer:

Move declaration of `i` outside the `click` handler.

```
var i=0;
$(".click").click(function(){
  if (i< audioArray.length){
     audioArray[i].trigger('play');
     i++;
  } else if ( i>audioArray.length){
     i = 0;
     audioArray[i].trigger('play');
  };
});
```

You were resetting it's value to 0 each time user clicked the button.

Comment: Cool, Yeah I knew the iteration was off but couldn't see what it was exactly. Thanks! However, how would I approach stopping the current playing audio file so only one audio file is playing? Every time I click it keeps playing a new audio file without stopping and resetting the former audio file.

Comment: thanks for your help. I'm currently just leveraging html5 native audio with jquery for DOM manipulation. The iterating works as every click trigger the next song in the array, however, the songs don't stop and reset as anticipated. Console doesn't appear to note any errors either so I'm curious if there's another method to stop the audio and reset it so the next song plays alone as opposed to overlapping audio over audio like it currently does.

Comment: Also, once an audio file is finished playing, how do I reset its current time so it can play again if looped back to the current song?

Comment: Hey @PeterLum, I've updated the answer again. Hope it helps.

Comment: @PeterLum, glad it helped. Please, mark the the answer as the solution :)